# Замена своего BB-тега на HTML-ссылку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражения для замены тега на ссылку с сохранением информации в теле тега.
Есть строчка

> Неизменная потертая соломенная шляпа, подаренная ему [character=727]Шанксом[/character], которую он, в свою очередь, получил от [character=4883]Роджера[/character]

Нужно привести строчку в такой вид

> Неизменная потертая соломенная шляпа, подаренная ему <a href="https://сайт.ру/character/Шанксом/727/">Шанксом</a>, которую он, в свою очередь, получил от <a href="https://сайт.ру/character/Роджера/4883/">Роджера</a>

Пробую так, получается белиберда на выходе

```
$description = preg_replace("/[character=[0-9]](.*?)[\/character]/Usi",
    '<a href=\"https://сайт.ру/character/\"$2\"/\"$1\"/\">$2<\/a>',$description);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace(';\[character=(\d+)\](.+?)\[/character\];i',
    '<a href="https://сайт.ру/character/$2/$1/">$2</a>', $description);
```

https://regex101.com/r/loAkHN/2

Чтобы применять обратные слэши по минимуму (для экранирования), используются одинарные кавычки — внутри них не работают спец. последовательности, и таким образом мы можем спокойно записать обратный слэш в строку. Кроме того, в качестве ограничителей регулярки применяются точки с запятой по краям. Единственное, что пришлось заэкранировать, — квадратные скобки, чтобы движок регулярных выражений PCRE не воспринимал бы их как группу символов.

Comment: модификатор `i` в этом шаблоне не требуется.

Comment: @Эдуард, не соглашусь с вами, вдруг я захочу бб-код заглавными набрать.

Comment: @Visman это конечно же целиком и полностью ваше право, но что значит _вдруг_? Не пользователь диктует разработчику, что писать, а разработчик пользователю. И если в разделе FAQ заявлено использование bb-кодов строчными символами, то все остальные символы считаются не валидными.

Comment: @Эдуард, лучше посмотрите в вопрос на регулярку и ее флаги. P.S.  И даже если у меня в faq прописаны все бб-коды строчными, то парсер при разборе введенного текста и его проверке понимает бб-коды написанные как строчными, так и заглавными буквами и переводит их в строчные перед сохранением в базу. Скрипту это сделать не трудно.

Comment: спасибо, этот вариант сработал как и задумывалось.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант:

```
$string = 'Неизменная потертая соломенная шляпа, подаренная ему [character=727]Шанксом[/character], которую он, в свою очередь, получил от [character=4883]Роджера[/character]';

$pattern = '~\[(character)=(\d+)](\w+)\[/\1]~u';
$replace = '<a href="https://сайт.ру/$1/$3/$2/">$3</a>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: @Visman вот почему я говорил про модификатор `i` - при учёте регистра в строке замены можно использовать ссылку на подмаску.

Comment: @Visman Если уж очень хочется использовать регистронезависимый bb-тег, то модификатор `i` можно применить конкретно к тегу: `(?i:character)` Но только в этом случае такой тег нельзя уже будет подставлять в строку замены, т.к. там нужны строчные символы.

Comment: 1. В строку замены нет ни какого смысла ставить тег. 2. выигрыша от `(?i:character)` тоже нет. Плюс вашей регулярки только в `(\w+)`, это безопасней по сравнению с `(.+?)`.

Comment: @Visman _В строку замены нет ни какого смысла ставить тег_ - вы затеваете спор ради спора? Если вы посмотрите в ПП, то увидите, что после доменного имени идёт не что иное, как имя тега. Более того, плюс моего шаблона ещё и в том, что он может быть полностью динамическим, если его не конкретизировать конкретным названием, а записать примерно так: `'~\[([a-z\d]+)=(\d+)](\w+)\[/\1]~u'`